# external style sheet isn't working

Tags: html

Hi there I'm having issues with my HTML not wanting to recognize my external style sheet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<!-- Brock Paradise 4/28/18 -->
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title> Brock Paradise R&#233sum&#233 </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
 <link rel=stylesheet" type='text/css'
  href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
 
 </head>
 
 <header>
 <h2> Oakland Brock Paradise R&#233sum&#233 </h2>
 </header>

 <body>
 
 <nav> 
 <ul>
<li> <a href="#Summary"> Summary </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#Contact"> Contact Information </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#Skills"> Skills </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#Education"> Education </a> </li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 
 <main>
 <h2> Contact Information </h2>
 <p id="Contact">
 <ul> 
 <li> Oakland Brock Paradise </li>
 <li> 918 East Alabama Avenue </li>
 <li> Albertville, Alabama, 35950 </li>
 <li> (256) 506-0522 </li>
 <li> oakland.paradise@gmail.com </li>
 </ul>
 </p>
 <h2> Summary </h2>
 <p id="Summary">
 Graduated from Boaz High School with an advanced diploma and currently attending Snead State Community College with a General Education major. Worked at Snead State Community College as a baseball manager attending to the players and umpires needs while keeping the inventory and making sure everything was cleaned and in its proper place. Volunteered at Hamacon a convention in Huntsville, Alabama where I was part of registration and also helping out anywhere that was needed.  I’ve also worked for Marshall Medical South as a shuttle driver for a short period improving my communication skills and my ability to get where I need to be in a timely manner.
 </p>
 <style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
} 

th,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table.a {
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 180px;    

}
</style>
<p id="Education">
 <h2> Education </h2>
<table class="a">
  <tr>
    <th>School</th>
    <th>Degree/Diploma</th>
    <th>Graduated Year</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Boaz High</td>
    <td>Advanced Diploma</td>
    <td>May 2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Snead State</td>
    <td>General Education</td>
    <td>May 2018</t>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
 <h2> Employment History </h2>
 <ul>
 <li> Snead State Baseball Manager from August 2014 - May 2015 </li>
 <li> Volunteered at Hamacon a convention in Huntsville, Alabama from 2017 - Present </li>
 <li> Marshall Medical South shuttle driver from Septemper 2017 - Febuary 2018 </li>
 </ul>
 <p id="Skills">
 <h2> Professional Skills </h2>
 <ul>
 <li> Management </li>
 <li> Sanitation </li>
 <li> Inventory Work </li>
 <li> Communication </li>
 <li> Teamwork </li>
 <li> Organization </li>
 <li> Multitasking </li>
 <li> Priortization </li>
 <li> Adaptablility </li>
 <li> Time Management </li>
 <li> Quick Learner </li>
 <li> Driving </li>
 </ul>
 </p>
 <style>
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<img class="responsive" src="Images/Thumbsup.jpg" alt="Thumbsup"  width="400" height="100">
 </main>
 </body>
 
 <footer>
 <p> Brock Paradise 2018&copy;</p>
 </footer>
 
 </div>

</html>
```

That's my current code and these:

https://gyazo.com/ac9fd81a642a7c0004056be68ac140aa

https://gyazo.com/d179a47cfd5e5b7ba4997617d21c6672?token=f93f8d160431f2913bcc6d388cd4eb05

are the file locations
I cannot figure out why it's not working and I'm really new at this so sorry If I'm not much help.

Comment: Try this `<link rel=stylesheet" type='text/css'
  href="C:\CIS207 FINAL PROJECT\CSS\stylesheet.css">`

Comment: Please consider pasting/posting directly instead of just links.

Comment: StackOverflow is very picky about this. Links can be unreliable.

Comment: Congratulations on your first post! In the future, you may want to keep external links to a minimum, like JDOaktown said, they can be unreliable. Also, I ran across a few errors in your code. If you're new to HTML, I'd suggest running your code through an [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) before you hand it in. I made a few edits to your file if you'd like to look them over and see the differences. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatTastic/7nnxy9b0/).

Answer (score 0):

From the file you sent you are missing a closing tag at the end of your meta tag.

Change from this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Brock Paradise R&#233sum&#233 </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
  <link rel=stylesheet" type='text/css' href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

To this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Brock Paradise R&#233sum&#233 </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks I saw that later but it made no difference sadly.

Comment: including the quotation mark  that was edited in on the rel="stylesheet"

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/285310734366408704/440677548842811403/Final_Project_TEXT_PATCH_2.txt
This is the current edited version. I have been told my issue is that I'm using windows I don't know how true that is.

Comment: Haha your current vertion says "stylessheet.css" and not "stylesheet.css". See if that helps

Comment: But as people here said, when you want to make updates to your code, just do an update to your original post and avoid sending external links especially to files